# Derive $\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, derivatives, polynomials

I try to derive $\frac{1}{x}$.

I try to do it with the $x_0$ method.

I have $m=\frac {f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0-x}$
I am using $\frac {1}{x} $ to replace $f(x_0)$ and $f(x)$.

Now we have
$m=\frac {\frac {1}{x_0}-\frac {1}{x}}{x_0-x} $

However I want to derive so I need to shorten $x_0-x$ in the denominator. So I need to have anothe $x_0-x$ in the numerator.

I basically need to do: $\left(\frac {1}{x_0}-\frac {1}{x}\right)÷(x_0-x)$

However here I get stuck. It would be nice if someone could help me to calculate this division.

Comment: Basically, whenever you see a sum or difference of fractions, don't even think of telling me that you're stuck: try making a common denominator first.

Comment: Also, the divison symbol ÷ is not used in higher mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{\frac{1}{x}- \frac{1}{x_0}}{x - x_0} = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{\frac{x_0 - x}{xx_0}}{x-x_0} = -\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{x-x_0}{xx_0(x-x_0)} = -\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{1}{xx_0} = \frac{-1}{x_0^2}$$

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. However I do not understand how you simplify $\frac {1}{x}-\frac {1}{x0}$ to $\frac {x0-x}{xx0}$

Comment: Let me write it out in detail for you: $$\frac{x_0-x}{xx_0} = \frac{x_0}{xx_0} - \frac{x}{xx_0} = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x_0}$$. Is it clear now? In general, $$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad + bc}{bd}$$

Comment: Ok I understood it. Can you please explain me why $x_0-x $ is changed to $x-x_0$?

Comment: There is a minus sign in front of the limit, because $x_0-x = -(x-x_0)$

Answer (score 1):

Add the fractions:

$$\frac{1}{x_0}-\frac{1}{x} = \frac{x-x_0}{xx_0} = \frac{-(x_0-x)}{xx_0}.$$

Now you can easily cancel the factor you want.

Comment: I think that your last equality is wrong.

Comment: @Gödel indeed, the difference in parentheses should be flipped.

Comment: @Gödel Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: @B.Goddard you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Make a common denominator in the numerator,

$$\frac{\frac{x}{x_0x}-\frac{x_0}{x_0x}}{x_0-x}$$

Now simplify.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{x_0}-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x-x_0}{xx_0}$$